# How do you make a Solr query to return a range of words around the specific word you queried?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

Say I have the following solr/lucene query:

https://some_website.com//api/myapi/search?profile=myprofile&fl=*&fq=batchid:*,bodytextsize_i*&q=word_i_want_to_search&partner=mypartnerid&rows=10

I would like to know what I can add to this in order to have the sentence or a certain range of words around the query word returned to me in the response. For instance say a document has the following sentence:

*The computer's **word_i_want_to_search** is broken.*

I would like to be able to query word_i_want_to_search and have the response show me the entire sentence. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is [known as highlighting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html):

> Highlighting in Solr allows fragments of documents that match the
>   user’s query to be included with the query response.
>
> The fragments are included in a special section of the query response
>   (the highlighting section), and the client uses the formatting clues
>   also included to determine how to present the snippets to users.
>   Fragments are a portion of a document field that contains matches from
>   the query and are sometimes also referred to as "snippets" or
>   "passages".

Use the parameters `hl=true&hl.fl=field_you_are_searching` and go from there. There's a lot of small things you can tweak to get different behaviors, such as how much data is being included in the response.